# Bind and Unbind mousewheel on popup image event - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, mousewheel

```js
$(document).on("click", ".test", function(z) {
  $("body").bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;

  });

});
```

I can stop mousewheel from scrolling the background when the popup image shows ... and I can do it by the following code.

So, I'm here trying to find a way to unbind and scroll the background again. After closing popup, all elements are blocked. The page doesn't scroll.

Any thoughts how to unbid it again?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not just unbind the event? http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: multiple clicks = multiple events bound. Not a good idea.

Comment: I'm using -magnificPopup- on a parallax environment with auto scroll. the only way I managed to block the background was by the up code. Now i can't unblock to return the browsing on the same page. I have tried to .unbind() but with no practical effect...

Comment: I'm dying here... Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.unbind()`?

```
$(document).on("click", ".test", function(z) {
  $("body").bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
  });
});

$(document).on("click", ".unbind_button", function() {
  $("body").unbind("mousewheel", function() {
    // do something
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah... doesn't work. It's the same. Maybe the problem relies on the fact that the image only closes with a click outside it "on the real page background". If I click on the popup, it shows other pictures.